# Scalatest aborted tests handling

Tags: scala, testing, handle, scalatest, abort

Is there any way how to handle an aborted test in ScalaTest? I'm using `withFixture` method, but I didn't find "Aborted" type:

```
override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest) = {
  super.withFixture(test) match {
    case failed: Failed => {
      insertScreen
      failed
    }
    case canceled: Canceled => {
      insertScreen
      canceled
    }
    //case aborted: **** => {something}
    case other => other
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ScalaTest, Suites can complete or abort, tests can have one of four outcomes: succeeded, failed, canceled, or pending. An aborted suite means that some exception is thrown *outside* the context of a running test, such as in before/after code or the constructor invocation. None of those places would ever send an exception or result status through withFixture, because withFixure always executes during the execution of some test.

Comment: Thank you. Aborted state was caused by using assume instead of assert in tests - now it works pretty well.